# Professional vector editing software for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, software-rec

**Not** from Adobe package.
For creating professional quality stock vector sets.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: If you provide more information why you don't want to use Adobe software, that'd help us answer the question...

Comment: @jtbandes: This is a QA website, so question it is, sorry for brevity. It will be hard to list all I want and don't like in Adobe, at the same time professional vector editing software are limited, so I will just see from recommendations. Essential features I need is creating complex vector objects easily.

Answer (score 2):

[Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/). It can generate image files, or even code to draw the images with Core Graphics.

Answer (score 2):

[Hicks Design](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/journal/fireworks-alternatives-on-trial-acorn-drawit-and-opacity) has a nice overview of [Acorn](http://flyingmeat.com/acorn/), [Drawit](http://bohemiancoding.com/drawit/) and [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/). One of those three may fit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you given [Lineform](http://www.freeverse.com/mac/product/?id=6020), [DrawIt](http://www.bohemiancoding.com/) or [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) a try?

I don't have any personal experience with them but have seen them recommended many times.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use Inkscape, but I know it runs in the X11 environment on Mac OS X and some people do not like that it does not conform to the Cocoa look and feel.

What is nice about Inkscape is that it produces standards-compliant SVG as well, which is particularly helpful as more browsers add true SVG support.  If you are designing for the web, this can be a very handy substitute for Flash when combined with Javascript.

Don't let the low version number fool you with Inkscape.  It is a quite capable application.